# Pass the current parameter to function in a loop

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to print multiple rect out. Now I'hope the rect could allow user click on it and the active some function.

For example, there are 3 rectangles, `"Tom"`, `"Mary"` and `"Ben"`. When user click on different rect, it will pass the current value. Like when I click on `"Tom"` it will pass `"Tom"` to call the function.

However, I found that after finish print out the rect, no matter I click on which rect, they both return the least value of the dataset.

In my example, even I click on `"Tom"` or `"Mary"`, both return `"Ben"`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ward_set.length; i++) {
  var ward_id = ward_set[i];
  legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", legend_x + 180 + 100 * n)
    .attr("y", legend_y)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .attr("fill", colors[count])
    .attr("class", "legend" + ward_set[i])
    .on("click", function() {
      console.log(ward_id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question perfectly illustrates a very important principle, a rule of thumb if you like, when writing a D3 code: **never use a loop** to append elements. Use the enter/update/exit pattern instead.

What happens when you use a loop (be it `for`, `while`, `forEach` etc...) is that not only there is no data binding, but also you experience this strange outcome you described (getting always the last value), which is explained here: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5768908)

Therefore, the solution using a D3 idiomatic enter selection would be:

```
const data = ["Tom", "Mary", "Ben"];

const svg = d3.select("svg");

const rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  //etc...
```

Then, in the `click` listener, you get the first argument, which is the datum:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
})
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const data = ["Tom", "Mary", "Ben"];

const svg = d3.select("svg");

const rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("x", (_, i) => i * 60)
  .on("click", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```